# How to Show pandas Data Frame in tkinter GUI inside the gui screen?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-interface, tkinter

I have a data frame and want to show it inside Tkniter GUI

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')  
df.head()
```

I load the df with pandas but I cannot show it in GUI.
Does anybody have any solution for this?

Comment: Check out the pandastable module. https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable

Comment: You've told us what you want, but you didn't ask a question. There are lots of tutorials about how to use tkinter, and lots of documentation for the various widgets. What part of creating the GUI do you need help with?

Answer (score 3):

[tkintertable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable) is a solution to use pandas df. you can also use [pandastable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable) instead which is better.

with pandastable it is easy as:

```
import pandastable as pt

dTDa1 = tkinter.Toplevel()
dTDa1.title('TestData')
dTDaPT = pt.Table(dTDa1, dataframe=yourdf, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
dTDaPT.show()
```

Comment: Maybe include a short example usage too?

Comment: Added an axample